# Logic behind skeleton data fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

I've implemented a skeleton approach when fetching data and visually, it's really user-friendly.
But my problem is that the skeleton is (logically) shown each time I navigate through the app.
I've noticed some apps on Internet showing skeleton just once.
What's the logic behind this?

Comment: This usually means client side caching through various JavaScript libraries such as [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/).

Comment: Ok. But how can I ensure I delivered updated view?